# USB Wireless keyboards not registering Ctrl Alt Delete when computer boots

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb, keyboard

I've recently installed a new PC at work. Its a Dell Optiplex 9010. I bought a USB wireless keyboard and mouse from Dell and subsequently from Logitech to use with this PC. The Dell keyboard is a model KM632 and the logitech is an mk260. Both units work properly and have decent range.

The issue is when the PC boots they keyboard (neither model) will register a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to the PC. I can say for sure the keyboards are still functional as the media keys will still produce a result (notably the sleep key on the mk260). My gut reaction is I'm dealing with an issue in the PC or Windows. I'm not sure where to start though. If I unplug and reinsert the USB dongle both units will work. Also, I don't use both they keyboards at the same time I bought the Logitech fearing the Dell unit was bad.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of your current BIOS ? (Press F2 or F12 to Bios access)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of computers does not support USB wireless keyboard during boot, and will first accept incoming key strokes when inside the OS.

You could try and use different USB ports on the computer to see if that will do the trick if you haven't.

Else, get a wired USB keyboard, and get into the BIOS that way. When inside try to look for an option called something like Legacy USB Support, a few times this solved this problem.